# Call a function on a large number of columns in an R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

As input, consider 99 columns named p01 to p99 in a data frame. 
I'll use 6 in this example to keep it manageable.

```
p01 p02 p03 p04 p05 p06
14  76 153 155 163 175
85  89 105 155 166 167
15  26 167 257 313 318
 2 105 162 171 177 221
```

As output, we want a new column "result" that pastes these columns together, separated by a "-", like this:

```
p01 p02 p03 p04 p05 p06                result
14  76 153 155 163 175 14-76-153-155-163-175
85  89 105 155 166 167 85-89-105-155-166-167
15  26 167 257 313 318 15-26-167-257-313-318
 2 105 162 171 177 221 2-105-162-171-177-221
```

Code to reproduce this data structure is

```
 mini=structure(list(p01 = c(14, 85, 15, 2), p02 = c(76, 89, 26, 105
), p03 = c(153, 105, 167, 162), p04 = c(155, 155, 257, 171), 
p05 = c(163, 166, 313, 177), p06 = c(175, 167, 318, 221)), 
.Names = c("p01", "p02", "p03", "p04", "p05", "p06"), 
row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Below is a way to do this, but it requires naming 6 variables in the function definition and 6 variables in the function call. This doesn't scale to 99 or 999 columns. How does one define and call functions on large numbers of columns in a data frame?

```
myhash=function(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6) {
  return(paste(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,sep="-"))
}
vmyhash=Vectorize(myhash)
mini$result=vmyhash(mini$p01, mini$p02,
                   mini$p03, mini$p04,
                   mini$p05, mini$p06)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mini$result <- apply(mini,1,paste,collapse="-")
```

**EDIT** (Response to OP's comment)

As @Roland points out, you can pass any function to `apply(...)`, including UDF. So

```
f <- function(x) paste(x[order(x)],collapse="-")
mini$result <- apply(mini,1,f)
```

You can also define an "anonymous" function directly in `apply(...)`:

```
mini$result <- apply(mini,1,function(x) paste(x[order(x)],collapse="-"))
```

This is shorter but makes the code harder to read.

Finally, here's sorting in reverse order, just to show that it's doing something:

```
apply(mini,1,function(x) paste(x[order(-x)],collapse="-"))
# [1] "175-163-155-153-76-14" "167-166-155-105-89-85" "318-313-257-167-26-15" "221-177-171-162-105-2"
```

Comment: Can this be modified to take a user-defined function that takes a large number of parameters?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit. This will create a "hash" that pastes together the values from *all columns*, separated by "-". Do you want something different?

Comment: I'm looking for a more general answer, so instead of "paste" we call a user-defined function. For example, what if you wanted to sort the values such that p01 is the smallest number and p06 is the largest number before you make the hash (pretend they're not already sorted in the example).

Comment: @DanGoldstein You can pass user defined functions to `apply`. Study the help page and look at the examples there.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension of jlhowards answer which should be close to what you want. It's too long for a comment...

```
> (m1 <- t(data.frame(x1=c(1,2,10,9),
+                  x2=c(8,10,1,2))))
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
x1    1    2   10    9
x2    8   10    1    2
> f1 <- function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse="-")
> (apply(m1, 1, f1))
        x1         x2 
"1-2-9-10" "1-2-8-10"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another simple way to paste the values together:

```
mini$result <- gsub(" ", "-", Reduce(paste, mini))

  p01 p02 p03 p04 p05 p06                result
1  14  76 153 155 163 175 14-76-153-155-163-175
2  85  89 105 155 166 167 85-89-105-155-166-167
3  15  26 167 257 313 318 15-26-167-257-313-318
4   2 105 162 171 177 221 2-105-162-171-177-221
```